# Ring homomorphisms, ideals and quotient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $R$ be a ring and $I \subset R$ an ideal. The canonical map $\pi : R \to R/I$ is defined by sending $r \mapsto r+I$. Then $\ker(\pi) = I$.

I have hard time understanding this definition. I've looked at the example where $\pi : \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/ \Bbb Z_n$ and $\pi(a) =a + \Bbb Z_n$.

I understand that if $\pi$ was defined to be $\pi(a)=a \pmod{n}$, then I would have that $$\ker(\pi)=\{a \in \Bbb Z \mid \pi(a)=0\} = \{a \in \Bbb Z \mid a \equiv 0 \pmod{n}\} = n\Bbb Z = \Bbb Z /\Bbb Z_n$$ which gives me the right result.

However I don't see how I can get the result with the more general map $\pi(r)=r+ I$. How is it true that $$\ker(\pi)= \{r \in R \mid r+I=0 \} = I?$$

The elements of $R/I$ are of form $r+ I$ as determined by $\pi$, but $$r+I=\{r+i \mid i \in I\}$$ and so if I have  $$r+I= 0 \iff \{r+i \mid i \in I\} = \{0\}$$ but this still doesn't look like the kernel of $\pi$. What am I not understanding here?

Answer (score 1):

We have $I\subseteq \ker(\pi)$, because $\pi(I)=I+I=I=0$ in $R/I$. Conversely, let $x\in \ker(\pi)$. Then $0=\pi(x)=x+I$ in $R/I$, so that $x+I=I$, and hence $x\in I$.